# onclick running when page loads

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have some code in javascript that I just want the object to change when I click on it, but it runs the code as if I have already clicked on the object as soon as the page loads

```
"use strict";

function changeText(obj){
    obj.innerHTML = "DON'T CLICK ME!";
}

function init(){
    var obj = document.getElementById("xPhoto");
    obj.onclick = changeText(obj);
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: You're already doing this with `window.onload = init;`. Apply the same principle: `obj.onclick = changeText;`. Namely, don't call the function. Assign it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the `changeText` function in `init` so you are setting `obj.innerHTML = "DON'T CLICK ME!"` on `init`

Based on your description, you want to assign the `chagneText` to the `onclick` of `obj`, something like: `obj.onclick = changeText`

Comment: Thank you, didn't realise that having it as `changeText(obj)` instead of just `changeText` was causing it to run it as the page load